# why the default value of p1 is set to 0 and is incremented by 1 each time

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, integer

When I run the simple code snippet below

```
Integer[] one = new Integer[10];

Arrays.setAll(one, p1 -> p1 * p1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
```

the result returned is

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

which implies that the default value of `p1` started from 0 and is incremented by 1 each time. I was just wondering why the default behaviour is set this way and where I can find some additional reading on this type of default behaviour?

Comment: What does the docs say about the parameter that the lambda gets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `setAll(int[] array, IntUnaryOperator generator)` method, which applies the passed unary operator to the index of the array.

Hence

```
one[0] == 0 * 0
one[1] == 1 * 1
one[2] == 2 * 2
...
```

From the Javadoc :

> **generator** a function accepting an index and producing the desired value for that position

Comment: Thank you so much!! simple yet precise!!